# Regular Expression for relative links ONLY

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a javascript that checks for links in the DOM and changes those who are NOT absolute links. Unfortunately I'm not having any luck...

I would like to match only the first type of links below, and add a folder path

1. `<a href="somepage.html">link</a>`
2. `<a href"http://somesite.net/somepage.html">link</a>`

I've used `string.replace(/a.+href="([^http]+)"/, 'path'+$1);` to no avail...

Can someone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What overall problem are you trying to solve?  I feel like there's probably a simpler solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Basically what I want is to have a regular expression that only checks for relative paths in a link tag, therefore avoiding absolute urls.

Answer (score 2):

If the regular expression that you've written to solve a problem using just regular expressions starts to look like overkill, then it is probably overkill. Sometimes a simple `if` statement used in conjunction with regular expressions can do wonders:

```
$("a").each(function () {
    if (!/^http:\/\//.test(this.href)) {
        this.href = "http://example.com/folder/" + this.href; // etc.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `<base>` html tag, instead. It allows you to set the path to which all links and images are relative.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-base-element

Answer (score 0):

You've created a character class with the square brackets. Remove them. You want a "negative lookbehind", see comment below for info on syntax. Not all languages support this regex feature though.

Javascript doesn't support lookbehind. This may help though: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: but then how can I negate "http" in the href attribute without the usage of brackets and the caret character?

Comment: I think with a "negative lookbehind". I'm uncertain on the exact syntax :: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: javascript does support negative look*ahead* though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string.replace(/(a.+href=)"(?!http)(.+)"/gi, '$1"path/$2"')
```

Answer (score 0):

for example sake, I just made a variable with a couple links in it.  You can easily adapt the .replace() to work with however you get the links.

```
var content = '<a href="/somepage.html">link</a><a href="http://somesite.net/somepage.html">link</a><a href="somepage.html">link</a>';

// whatever you want to prefix link with
var base='http://somsite.net';

content = content.replace(/(href=")(?!https?:\/\/)([^"]*)/gi,'$1'+base+'/$2').replace(/\/+/g,'/');
```

Comment: so this regular expression only replaces relative paths, avoiding absolute urls?

Comment: It looks for href=" and then matches everything up to the next " but only if what comes after href=" doesn't start with http:// or https:// and if it finds it, it will prefix the url with whatever is in that base variable. Also an additional replace() to replace double // that might occur, if for instance the relative url starts with a /  vs. not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

I was able to replace relative paths ONLY by using the following syntax:

```
var basepath = "pathto/";
var html = html.replace(/(<(a|img)[^>]+(href|src)=")(?!http)([^"]+)/g, '$1'+basepath+'$4');
```